# error when adding one signal dependency

Tags: android, onesignal

I want to use **OneSignal** in my android app but I get some errors after adding OneSignal dependency in my gradle file.

I am using Android Studio 3.1.

This is my gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nasser.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:2.2.2'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]'
}
```

and this is project's build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

now when i sync gradle file i get many errors like this one:

```
Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.2.0).
Required by:
project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5
 > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.2.0).
> Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
                           > dl.google.com:443 failed to respond
```

Comment: Use code formatting. Otherwise it's hard to read the code in the post.

Comment: sorry, i used my phone for posting question, you right.

Comment: `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` is the same as `google()`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the google maven in your **project** build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

You need to remember that OneSignal automatically adds the following dependencies:

```
com.google.android.gms - Version 11.2.+  
com.android.support - Version 26.1.+
```

So, all dependencies must have matching versions.

To force the support library which your selected version, you can use the following:

```
// Must use 26.0.0 or newer if you have targetSdkVersion 26
def androidSupportVersion = '26.1.+'
compile("com.android.support:support-v4:${androidSupportVersion}")  {
    force = true
}
compile("com.android.support:customtabs:${androidSupportVersion}")  {
    force = true
}
```

Read more at [Troubleshooting Android](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android).

---

p.s: You should fix your `build.gradle`.

Comment: how i can add this libraries to myproject? this error occures just after adding compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]' to dependencies.

Comment: thank you for reply, but i am new in android, could you tell me please how i should match dependencies? or where i should put your code [def androidSupportVersion = ... ]?

Comment: Ohhh... I see. You need to use the same version of support library which is contain `com.android.support`. For dependency, you need to add inside the `dependencies { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in Android Studio 3.1, and all build tasks are failed.

Finally I found my problem is caused by Gradle proxy setting. The solution:

Open the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties, and delete proxy settings in it if any, like

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=50846
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=50846
```

then restart Android Studio, build tasks works now.